# Passing arguments in c functions

Tags: c, function

I'm newbie in c. I have written a function in c and passes the arguments to it but I got different answers as I expect.

The function is

```
void GridDim(float long1, float long2, float dx,
             float lat1, float lat2, float dy,
             float depth1, float depth2, float dh,
             int *m, int *n, int *k)
{
    *m = (int) ((long2-long1)/dx+1);
    *n = (int) ((lat2-lat1)/dy+1);
    *k = (int) ((depth2-depth1)/dh+1);
}
```

I used gcc to compile it:
gcc -c GridDim.c

then I used the object file for a main file and compile that file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
 int m,n,k;
 GridDim(20.0,30.0,0.1,10.0,15.0,0.1,5.0,20.0,5.0,&m,&n,&k);
 printf("m= %d\nn= %d\nk= %d\n", m, n, k);
 return 1;
}
```

gcc test.c -o test GridDim.o

but I did not get the correct answer.
Does anybody know why?

the answer should be 
    m=101 
    n=51 
    k=4 
but I got m=1 n=1 k=-12

Comment: What should be the "correct answer"?

Comment: Just a wild guess but may you forgot the () around the d?+1 terms (e.g. (long2-long1)/(dx+1))?

Comment: I don't know what's your expected correct answer, however please notice that in C the type cast `(int)some_value` is actually `floor(some_value)` which means `(int)0.9 == 0`. Also please use 0 as the return value of `main` when it exits normally.

Comment: @PengyuCHEN, or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, which makes the intention more clear

Comment: the answer should be m=101 n=51 k=4 but I got m=1 n=1 k=-12?????

Comment: please add expected result in the question, not as a comment

Comment: I rolled the question back to revision three because the changes by LihO altered the source code and the reported observed results, thus changing the question to one not asked by the OP. The results reported by the OP are symptomatic of a missing function declaration, and LihO’s changes concealed that by merging the sources into one module. It is okay to edit for formatting. It is not okay to edit to change the question fundamentally.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh right.. I was answering this question according when the source codes were merged. Until after refreshing this page I know where the problem is. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a function prototype for your GridDim function and include it in the file that contains your main method.

The reason is that unless the compiler has a function prototype that declares the types of the arguments it will promote all floats into doubles. At run-time your floats gets promoted into doubles and then passed to GridDim which reads the first half of the double and interprets it as a float. If you print the values inside GridDim you will see that the floats come in as corrupted values.

If you declare your method in a header file, e.g. GridDim.h:

```
#ifndef __GRID_DIM_DOT_H__
#define __GRID_DIM_DOT_H__

extern void GridDim(float long1, float long2, float dx, float lat1, float lat2, float dy, float depth1, float depth2, float dh, int* m, int* n, int* k);

#endif/*__GRID_DIM_DOT_H__*/
```

... and #include it in GridDim.c (to ensure that the definition matches the declaration):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GridDim.h"

void GridDim(float long1, float long2, float dx,
             float lat1, float lat2, float dy,
             float depth1, float depth2, float dh,
             int *m, int *n, int *k)
{
    printf("long1 =  %10.6f\n", long1);
    printf("long2 =  %10.6f\n", long2);
    printf("dx =     %10.6f\n", dx);
    printf("lat1 =   %10.6f\n", lat1);
    printf("lat2 =   %10.6f\n", lat2);
    printf("long1 =  %10.6f\n", dy);
    printf("depth1 = %10.6f\n", depth1);
    printf("depth2 = %10.6f\n", depth2);
    printf("dh =     %10.6f\n", dh);

    *m = (int) ((long2-long1)/dx+1);
    *n = (int) ((lat2-lat1)/dy+1);
    *k = (int) ((depth2-depth1)/dh+1);
}
```

... and #include it in Main.c to ensure that the call matches the declaration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "GridDim.h"

int main()
{
 int m,n,k;
 GridDim(20.0f,30.0f,0.1f,10.0f,15.0f,0.1f,5.0f,20.0f,5.0f,&m,&n,&k);
 printf("m= %d\nn= %d\nk= %d\n", m, n, k);
 return 1;
}
```

... then the arguments will be passed correctly to the GridDim function. I added some printf statements so that you can see this.

If you comment out the #include "GridDim.h" in Main.c then you will see what is happening in your current version of the code:

```
long1 =    0.000000
long2 =    0.000000
dx =      -0.000000
lat1 =     0.000000
lat2 =     0.000000
long1 =   -0.000000
depth1 =   0.000000
depth2 =   0.000000
dh =       0.000000
m= 1
n= 1
k= -2147483648
```

With the #include the output looks like this:

```
long1 =   20.000000
long2 =   30.000000
dx =       0.100000
lat1 =    10.000000
lat2 =    15.000000
long1 =    0.100000
depth1 =   5.000000
depth2 =  20.000000
dh =       5.000000
m= 101
n= 51
k= 4
```

Comment: [+1] for header file usage. personally I like using header files.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing declaration of function.   `Declare  function before main()`

```
void GridDim(float long1, float long2, float dx,
           float lat1, float lat2, float dy,
             float depth1, float depth2, float dh,
             int *m, int *n, int *k);
```

And compile both files at a time

```
gcc main.c griddim.c -o result
./result
```

Comment: I didn't see OP saying anything about undefined reference to `GridDim`
FYI...he's able to compile and run

Comment: @P0W That's because you can use a function without a prototype in C, but I think, Gangadhar got the problem right. However, please add something on header file usage, Gangadhar, because putting forward declarations into other files than one header file that's also included by the file with the function definition for signature checking is a sure road to disaster (it's the reason I don't upvote yet).

Comment: @P0W: It is possible to compile and run with a missing function declaration in old C implementations, and this may produce the results the OP reports, as the arguments would not be passed properly with a missing declaration. This answer is the only one so far that explains the observed results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil _may_ , _may not_, _may be_ should be first confirmed as comment. I **may** think there's `GridDim` with some different definition too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Also after correcting using this will OP not be getting `100 50 4` ?

Comment: @P0W: The results are implementation-dependent. In a C implementation that uses IEEE 754 with correct rounding, the results are 101, 51, and 4. Lower-quality C implementations may give different results. However, the fact that these results are correct, in the sense they are the results one would get with exact mathematics, is a bit of luck. When the source text `0.1` is converted to `double`, it is rounded up to a representable value. When 10 is divided by that value, the quotient is rounded down. The two errors happen to cancel, producing exactly 100, as desired.

Comment: @cmaster good idea to use header files.richj Added info about usage of header files. sorry, i am not adding additional info regarding header files. thanks

Comment: @EricPostpischil `It is possible to compile and run with a missing function declaration in old C implementations.` and `The results are implementation-dependent` Indeed info.thanks

Comment: @Gangadhar Hey about your last comment, I've been remembering that it's standardized that functions without prototypes would be treated as having its parameters and return values of `int`.. Sorry I'm at dinner and not so convenient to find it in a document.

Comment: @Gangadhar Well it's in section `6.5.2.2 Function calls` of `ISO/IEC 9899:201x`: `If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions.`

Comment: @EricPostpischil _"The results are implementation-dependent"_ agreed. But what all about _"producing exactly 100, as desired"_ and from OP's _"the answer should be m=101.."_ No answer takes this point into consideration.

Comment: @P0W: The cause of the reported results is the missing declaration. If the OP has another problem after that is fixed, they can enter another question. If it is due to floating-point rounding, it will be closed as a duplicate, as that has been addressed numerous times on Stack Overflow. (This one should likely be closed as a duplicate as well; surely a missing declaration has been addressed numerous times.)

Answer (score 1):

As I've said in the comments, the type cast `(int)` in `C` does trimming, e.g. `(int)0.9 == 0`. Here you may want to use the function `round` provided by `math.h`

The following code solves your problem.

```
#include <math.h>
void GridDim(float long1, float long2, float dx,
             float lat1, float lat2, float dy,
             float depth1, float depth2, float dh,
             int *m, int *n, int *k)
{
    *m = round((long2-long1)/dx+1);
    *n = round((lat2-lat1)/dy+1);
    *k = round((depth2-depth1)/dh+1);
}
```

**EDITED:**

Here's it's specified in the standard document, in Section 6 of `ISO/IEC 9899:TC2`:

> 6.3.1.4 Real ﬂoating and integer
>
> 1 When a ﬁnite value of real ﬂoating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool,
>   the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of
>   the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undeﬁned.50)

**AGAING EDITED:**

However I have to say that your original code produces your-correct-answers on my machine.   Please notice this problem is actually generated by the machine-dependent floating point number calculation:

Assuming your're calculating the product of `1.0` and `5.0`: `float x = 1.0 * 5.0`. Here due to the precision, your actual result MAY BE `5.000002` or `4.999998`, depends on the platform that runs this code.

So when it's `5.000002`, your type cast `(int)x` works since it just cast the result to `5`, however when it's `4.999998` it would be casted to `4`. And `round` would always produce your expected answers.

**AGAIN EDITED:**

Oh sorry I'm not pointing the exact reason of your problem! You're missing the function definition. Here I vote for @Gangadhar's answer.

Comment: This does not explain the results reported in the problem, “m=1 n=1 k=-12”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes that's true. Gangadhar's presenting the right answer I think.

Answer (score 0):

before storing the value in the variable you have to take ceil value. because in c 0.9999 value if you are converting into the int it will convert to zero so before storing the value you have to take ceil value.

```
void GridDim(float long1, float long2, float dx,
             float lat1, float lat2, float dy,
             float depth1, float depth2, float dh,
             int *m, int *n, int *k)
{

   *m = (int) (ceil((long2-long1)/dx)+1);
   *n = (int) (ceil((lat2-lat1)/dy)+1);
   *k = (int) ((depth2-depth1)/dh+1);
}
```

Comment: This does not explain the results reported in the problem, “m=1 n=1 k=-12”.

Comment: I'm not a down voter but I will leave a comment because I think srihari is nearly right about an additional problem in the code. *m = (ceil((long2-long1))/dx); would produce a better answer where (long2 - long1) is exactly divisible by dx.

Comment: @richj: Even if floating-point were the problem here, `ceil` is the wrong solution. That could make the answers too large.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I can see how it might make the grid too small, if we really don't mind creating an extra column of cells to hold entries on the far edge of the grid. Do you have a test case where the answer is too large please?

Comment: @richj: If you set the first three arguments to `GridDim` to `0.f, 210.f, 2.1f` and compile and execute with a C implementation that uses IEEE 754 with correct rounding, the result for `m` with `ceil` is 102, where exact mathematics would produce 101. This is because the source text `2.1f` is must be rounded down slightly when converted to a `float`, and the quotient `210.f / 2.1f` yields a number slightly greater than 100, so `ceil` makes it 101 (and then the one is added, making 102).